# Mixture of different phases at coexistance point

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, equilibrium

Consider a sealed jar filled with water and water vapor. Pressure and temperature of the jar is configured in such way that water and vapor coexist with each other (ie. chemical potentials of both phases match).

I wonder which of the following setup is more "stable":

1. Water vapor fills 1/3 of the jar's total volume while water fills 2/3 of the jar's total volume.
2. Water vapor fills 1/2 of the jar's total volume while water fills 1/2 of the jar's total volume.

By "stable," I mean no evaporation or condensation happens in the jar.

I think both setups are stable because chemical potentials do not depend on volume or particle count.

Is that right?

Comment: Evaporation and condensation are always happening. In equilibrium they are equal.

Comment: @JonCuster So (2) is more stable?

Comment: No, they are both equally happy. And you know that because both go to equilibrium. But thermodynamic equilibrium is not stasis or static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under equilibrium conditions we can have *any* amount of liquid to coexist with *any* amount of vapor. The only requirement is uniform $T$ and $P$, and the same $\mu$ in all phases.